# Prevent the second event firing when the first is invalid + asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two custom server validate methods associated to two drop downs respectively. So When there is a post back both the methods seems to fire. I need to prevent the second one from firing if the first fails validation. Here are the methods

```
protected void CustomValidatorCountryOfCitizenshipServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
}

protected void CustomValidatorSecondCountryOfCitizenshipServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
}
```

I tried setting causes validation of the second dropdown control to false which didnt work. I also set the args of the first method to false but it is true when the second method gets called. Could somebody help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a flag:

```
bool isValidated = false;

protected void CustomValidatorCountryOfCitizenshipServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    // Validation code
    isValidated = true;
}

protected void CustomValidatorSecondCountryOfCitizenshipServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if (!isValidated)
        return;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty straight forward!

Just set up a bool and preset it to default.

```
 bool isValid = false;
protected void CustomValidatorCountryOfCitizenshipServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
            {
              isValid = true; 
            }

protected void CustomValidatorSecondCountryOfCitizenshipServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
          if(!isValid)
          {
          }
        }
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer 2 hours ago?